# Access WITH..AS clause's column in WHERE clause in Oracle

Tags: oracle, union, common-table-expression

I have 2 tables :

Table_A

```
USERCODE|USERMOBILE|USERACCOUNT
001     |0123236556|ACC001
002     |0222222222|ACC002
```

Table_B

```
USERCODE|USERMOBILE
001     |0123236556
001     |0444444444
002     |0555555555
```

I want following output, which filter by `Table_A.ACCOUNT`

For example `USERACCOUNT = ACC001`

```
USERCODE|USERMOBILE
001     |0123236556
001     |0123236556
001     |0444444444
```

I try with following query but not work :

```
with tbl as
(select USERCODE,USERMOBILE from Table_A WHERE USERACCOUNT='ACC001' ) 
select * from tbl
union
select USERCODE,USERMOBILE from Table_B WHERE  Table_B.USERCODE = tbl.USERCODE
```

Error : Invalid identifier : tbl.USERCODE

Are there any way to achive my expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `UNION ALL` can't refer to the 1st query from the 2nd query.
Use the CTE:

```
WITH cte(USERCODE, USERMOBILE) AS
(SELECT USERCODE, USERMOBILE FROM Table_A WHERE USERACCOUNT = 'ACC001')
SELECT USERCODE, USERMOBILE FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT USERCODE, USERMOBILE 
FROM Table_B 
WHERE USERCODE = (SELECT USERCODE FROM cte)
```

If the CTE may return more than 1 rows, change to:

```
WHERE USERCODE IN (SELECT USERCODE FROM cte)
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to achieve the desired result you have to use Join -

```
SELECT USERCODE, USERMOBILE
  FROM Table_A
 WHERE USERACCOUNT='ACC001'
 UNION
SELECT USERCODE, USERMOBILE
  FROM Table_B B
  JOIN Table_A A ON B.USERCODE = A.USERCODE
```